# How can I retrieve phone number of caller in Twilio Flex?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am trying to retrieve caller phone number in the Flex plug-in.
Using the caller phone number, I need to change the URI of the CRMContainer.

I have tried following methods but can't find caller phone number.

**First** method: function parameter `task` does not have caller phone number.

```
flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback  = task => {
  if (!task) {
    return 'http://localhost:4000'
  }

  return 'http://localhost:4000/searchresults?type=ALL&status=ANY&phoneNumber=(213)777-8888&query='

}
```

**Second** method: function parameter `payload` does not have caller phone number.

```
flex.Actions.addListener("beforeAcceptTask", payload => {
  flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uri = 'http://localhost:4000/searchresults?type=ALL&status=ANY&phoneNumber=(213)777-8888&query='
});
```

**Third** method: function parameter `conn` does not have caller phone number.

```
    manager.voiceClient.
    addListener('incoming', conn => {
      flex.CRMContainer.uri  =  'http://localhost:4000/searchresults?type=ALL&status=ANY&phoneNumber=(213)777-8888&query='
  })
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you trying looking at the payload:

`payload.task.attributes` specifically:

`payload.task.attributes.from` ?